# FaceBook connect in Android

Tags: android, facebook, api, for-loop

I have Integrated Facebook in my Application.Take a FACEBOOK API from Github
But I don't want to display dialog box to Publish string on wall Post.

```
facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters,
new WallPostDialogListener());
```

What should I do in palce of this ...that dialog box will not come & After login I can Post on a Wall of Facebook..

Pls help me in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a remote page that gets called in dialog inside WebView(according to me). So you cannot bypass it. 
Copy the URL and paste it in browser you will see that page.